# Unable to create message queues in IBM MQ 7.5

Tags: ibm-mq

I am setting up my corporate laptop to install IBM MQ 7.5 and create a Queue Manager and create some queues inside it.

The installation of IBM MQ 7.5 got success.  My user id (Ex.malai) is linked to 'mqm' user group.

Creation of Queue Manager

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.3>crtmqm A24QM
WebSphere MQ queue manager created.
Directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\qmgrs\A24QM' created.
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.
Creating or replacing default objects for queue manager 'A24QM'.
Default objects statistics : 77 created. 0 replaced. 0 failed.
Completing setup.
Setup completed.
```

Starting the Queue Manager

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.3>strmqm A24QM
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'A24QM' starting.
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.
5 log records accessed on queue manager 'A24QM' during the log replay phase.
Log replay for queue manager 'A24QM' complete.
Transaction manager state recovered for queue manager 'A24QM'.
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'A24QM' started using V7.5.0.0.
```

The above command looks ok.  I launch the IBM MQ with my user id 'malai' and I see as below
[image]

The Queue Manager is Disconnected.  I do not see the tree icon to expand the Queue Manager to create the Queues.

When I try creating the Queue Manger from GUI it is giving the below output

```
****************************************
* Command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\runmqsc" TESTQM
* Input: DEFINE LISTENER('LISTENER.TCP') TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1414) CONTROL(QMGR)
****************************************
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2011.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
Starting MQSC for queue manager TESTQM.
AMQ8135: Not authorized.
No MQSC commands read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.
exitvalue = 20
```

And also, even though I see the manager is in running state, once in 4/5 seconds the up green arrow goes to down red arrow and comes back.

I dont see any error in AMQERR01

I understand it is something to do with user group, rights and permission.  Since this is a corporate laptop, I do not have admin rights to my computer (i can get temporarily).  It is a dev setup and I would like to know what configuration do I need to do in order for MQ 7.5 to run in my machine.

**Update:**
When I try execute runmqsc it throws the below error

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.3>runmqsc A24QM
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2011.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
Starting MQSC for queue manager A24QM.

AMQ8135: Not authorized.

No MQSC commands read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.
```

Output of amqsput

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.3>amqsput A24QM
Sample AMQSPUT0 start
MQCONN ended with reason code 2059
```

I got a network admin and tried running the MQ Explorer and the cmd with 'Administrator' privileges. Login the PC with my id 'malai' and right click the MQ and select 'Run as Administrator' and login with admin id.

By doing that both runmqsc and MQ explorer works great. Does that giving any clue.

Comment: What user ID did you run MQ Explorer with? Clearly the user you have has mqm authorities already or you would not be able to crtmqm and strmqm. Also, what EXACTLY does the queue manager error log (%MQ_DATA_PATH%\qmgrs\TESTQM\errors\AMQERR01.LOG) say? It will detail exactly the authority failure.

Comment: Also, can you run the amqsput sample? Or does that also fail?

Comment: on windows you can do "net localgroup" in the cmd to see in which groups you are. Also if it's a fresh MQ installation I think you should reboot the system after the installation. I think it even says so ? but not 100% sure.

Comment: @MoragHughson question updated with detailed.

Comment: Hi Morag asked for the following but you did not provide this:  "Also, what EXACTLY does the queue manager error log (%MQ_DATA_PATH%\qmgrs\TESTQM\errors\AMQERR01.LOG) say?"

Comment: See @JasonE's comment below. You need a reboot for the mqm group association to take effect properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add your UserId (malai) to the mqm group:

Open a Command Prompt and issue the following command:

```
net localgroup mqm malai /add
```

Then reboot Windows.  Yes, reboot, its Windows.  Then everything will work correctly with your UserId.

Also, why in the world are you installing MQ v7.5?  Support for MQ v7.5 ended in April 2018!!  Why didn't you install MQ v8.0 or v9.0 or v9.1??

Comment: Just to clarify why this works - mqm is the administrative MQ group, so any members of it can fully administer MQ. Also, any Administrator running with elevated permissions is also treated as though it is in the mqm group, hence why run as administrator worked for you but running as a user which is in the administrators group did not.

You need to sign out and in again to get the mqm group in your logon token, and you also need the queue manager to refresh its view of the mqm group which is hard when you cant run a command against it (refresh security), hence a reboot is the simplest option.

Comment: @Roger This solution didn't work.  User malai is already part of mqm group.  If I execute the above command it says 'The specified account name is already a member of the group.'.  Rebooted more than once and still the same error reported in my question.  fyi... I understand 7.5 is out of support, we are in the progress of upgrading to 9+.

Comment: Please provide the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG entries that corrispond to the `AMQ8135: Not authorized.` when you `runmqsc`.